# Flutter Test: Testing if a checkbox is checked on build

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, flutter-test

I have a dynamic form system that builds widgets based on a json. One of the components that can be parsed is a Checkbox and a default value is passed to determine whether or not it is checked/unchecked initially. I'm writing a unit test for this and am running into trouble with semantics.

My test begins with checking the widget has been built (the following test is successful)

```
//create form
await tester.pumpWidget(buildTestableWidget(testWidget));

//setup Finder
Finder widgetFinder = find.widgetWithText(FormCheckbox, "test checkbox");

//test for widget
expect(widgetFinder, findsOneWidget);
```

The `FormCheckbox` class is as follows

```
class FormCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  final forms.Checkbox component;

  FormCheckbox(this.component) : super(key: Key("${component.propertyKey().getId()}"));

  _FormCheckboxState createState() => _FormCheckboxState(component);
}

class _FormCheckboxState extends State<FormCheckbox> {
  _FormCheckboxState(this._component) {
    this.boxValue = _component.isDefaultSelected();
  }

  final forms.Checkbox _component;
  bool boxValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 6, bottom: 6),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Material(
            child: Checkbox(
                value: boxValue,
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    boxValue = newValue;
                  });
            })),
          title: Text("${_component.getLabel()}"),
        ));
  }

  String validator(String value) {
    //TODO: Implement validator
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
```

Which despite everything else, has a `Checkbox` component as a child which defaults to a boolean I can set (which I can confirm is definitely working properly).

I would expect, from looking at flutter's own tests for checkboxes [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/checkbox_test.dart) that I can use `getSemantics` and expect it to equal a `matchedSemantics` within which `isChecked = true` as shown here

```
//test default value
expect(
  tester.getSemantics(find.byType(Checkbox)),
  matchesSemantics(
    isChecked: true,
    hasEnabledState: true,
    isEnabled: true,
));
```

However the isChecked state is remaining as false, even after a tap with `await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key("1")));`

The error message given is

```
Expected: has semantics with actions: [] with flags: [
            SemanticsFlag:SemanticsFlag.isChecked,
            SemanticsFlag:SemanticsFlag.hasEnabledState,
            SemanticsFlag:SemanticsFlag.isEnabled
          ]
Actual: SemanticsNode:<SemanticsNode#5(Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 68.0), tags:
[RenderViewport.twoPane], flags: [hasEnabledState, isEnabled], label: "test checkbox",
textDirection: ltr)>
   Which: flags were: [hasEnabledState, isEnabled]
```

What am I missing here? Why is a created Checkbox object with value: true not giving a semantics value of isChecked = true

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.

Edit: Update after @brightknight08's comment

```dart
final checkboxFinder = find.byKey(const Key('aKey'));

var checkbox = tester.firstWidget<Checkbox>(checkboxFinder);
expect(checkbox.value, false);

await tester.tap(checkboxFinder);
await tester.pump();

checkbox = tester.firstWidget<Checkbox>(checkboxFinder);
expect(checkbox.value, true);
```

I think it works the same way with `find.byType(Checkbox)`.

Comment: I t works. But why we have to again create checkbox widget after pumping.
//checkbox = tester.firstWidget(checkboxFinder) as Checkbox;

Comment: This is to see that the "checkbox" has gone from false to true. @JarinRocks

Comment: you can also specify the type like such: `checkbox = tester.firstWidget<Checkbox>(checkboxFinder);`

Answer (score 1):

**another method:**

`expect(tester.widget<Checkbox>(find.byKey("your-key")).value, false);`

**or if you are using CheckboxListTile try the following**

`expect(tester.widget<CheckboxListTile>(find.byKey("your-key")).value, false);`

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(
        tester
            .getSemantics(find.text("First"))
            .getSemanticsData()
            .hasFlag(SemanticsFlag.hasCheckedState),
        true);
```

This approach avoids defining a key and provides more flexibility in the semantics.
Solution inspired by: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/checkbox_test.dart

Answer (score 1):

In an integration test, I wanted the checkbox value without using `expect`. Ryan Sneyd's answer got me half way there. This is what I ended up with:

```
import ...
import 'dart:ui'; // for SemanticsFlag

var checkboxValue = tester
        .getSemantics(find.bySemanticsLabel(RegExp(r"Checkbox label")))
        .getSemanticsData()
        .hasFlag(SemanticsFlag.isChecked);
```

Of course you could use this with `expect` via `expect(checkboxValue, false);`.